# scipy -- compute cumsum from pairs list

Tags: scipy

I have this :

```
 def steps(ns):
        return [random.choice([[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, 0]]) for i in range(ns)]
```

which returns for example for ns=4 : [[-1, 0], [0, -1], [1, 0], [1, 0]]

I want do sth like this :

```
def Walk(ns):
        return sc.cumsum(steps2d(ns))
```

in order to compute the cumsum from the above.I want for example to have :

Walk(10) : [[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2], [2, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 
  4], [0, 4]]

With the Walk function of mine i am taking sth like :

[1 1 1 2 2 3 3 2 2 3 4 4 3 3 4 4 4 3 3 4]

Is there a way to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `scipy.cumsum(..., axis=0)`.